# OpenGL shader complier throws random errors and fails to render

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glfw, glew

I am trying to write a simple code to draw a triangle on screen, but after finishing the basic code in c++, I've run into an issue where the shader compiler seems to throw random errors, different on every compile, generally appearing along the lines of:

```
failed to compile shader:: Operation timed out
ERROR: 0:X: 'text' : syntax error: syntax error
: Operation timed out
```

The text is usually either some sort of seemingly random command (none of which I could find in [docs.gl](http://docs.gl)), or a single ASCII character (brackets, punctuation signs, semicolons, uppercase and lowercase letters included). Sometimes, it doesn't throw anything, sometimes, it even throws a segfault, regardless of the presence of the error.

main.cpp:

```cpp
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int loadShader(const char* path, unsigned int type){
    FILE* file = fopen(path,"r");

    if(file==NULL){
        printf("\033[31mERROR:\033[0m failed to load shader file: %s\n", path);
        return 0;
    }
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(file);
    char* buffer = new char[size];
    rewind(file);

    if(!buffer){
        fclose(file);
        printf("\033[31mERROR:\033[0m failed to allocate memory to load shader file: %s\n", path);
        return 0;
    }

    if(1!=fread(buffer, size, 1, file)){
        fclose(file);
        printf("\033[31mERROR:\033[0m failed to read shader file: %s\n", path);
        return 0;
    }

    unsigned int shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &buffer, (int*)&size);
    glCompileShader(shader);    
    int status;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if(!status){
        char err[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, err);
        printf("\033[31mERROR:\033[0m failed to compile shader: %s\n", err);
    }
    std::cout<<"loaded shader successfully"<<std::endl;
    delete [] buffer;
    return shader;
}

int main(void){
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Aimless", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
    //GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr); // Fullscreen
    
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo); 
    
    GLuint vertexShader = loadShader("vertex.shader", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentShader = loadShader("fragment.shader", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);


    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){

        float vertices[] = {
             0.0f,  0.5f,// vertex 1
             0.5f, -0.5f,// vertex 2
            -0.5f, -0.5f // vertex 3
        };
        GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
        glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);

        GLuint vao;
        glGenVertexArrays(1,&vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

vertex.shader:

```
#version 150 core

in vec2 position;

void main()
{
     gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

fragment.shader:

```
#version 150 core

out vec4 color;

void main(){
    color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

I am compiling code on MacOS over CLI using:

```
clang++  -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo -lglfw -lglew main.cpp -o main.o
```

Answer (score 3):

Your memory allocation stuff is completely broken:

> ```
> char* buffer = new char(size);
> ```

That allocates *a single character* and initializes it to `size`.

What you wanted there was `new char[size]`.

You're doing the same stuff with your `err` message buffers.

Furthermore:

> ```
> if(!buffer){
> ```

That's not how the C++ `new` operator works. It will throw an exception if it can't allocate the memory, not return a `NULL` pointer.

And finally: you never `delete` your buffers, so you will be leaking memory when this function returns. (Note, when using the correct array syntax for the allocation as I showed earlier, the correct way to free is `delete [] buffer`).

Comment: That is... odd. After debugging with some std::cout's, it would appear that the file is successfully loaded in ```buffer``` in both your and mine examples, so id say that's not the issue. The issue of the shader compiler outputting gibberish still persists with your solution tough.

Comment: "After debugging with some std::cout's, it would appear that the file is successfully loaded in buffer in both your and mine examples, " Just that in your code, you're in undefined behavior land and may have overwritten data structures for whatever. Using `perror` for GL errors will also not work, that's only for errno from the standard libs. It is no wonder that it might report weird stuff like "operation timed out".

Comment: Right, i will replace them with the regular printf's and update the code here. I doubt i have overwritten them. The original issue has still not been adressed.

Comment: You also tell the compiler that your source string will be NUL-terminated, but unless you can guarantee that you put a 0-Byte at the end of your text file (which nobody does, and isn't really easy to do with usual text editors),, just is not the case.

Comment: Hm, that could be easily added in the main code itself. The code for the shaders is meant to be more or less standalone, so I dont see why I would add it there.

Comment: You know the sze anyway, so you can also just tell it to the compiler. That's what the last argument is for, after all. Just note that it is a pointer to an array of sizes, one for each source string.

Comment: I'm already loading the file into ```buffer``` as one string. making the ```buffer``` one byte longer and adding ```(char)0``` at the end seems much simpler than having to generate new array pointer and record size of each string.

Comment: Since it is only one string anyway, so the "array" just has to be one element, and you already have it, so conceptually, `glShaderSource(shader, 1, &buffer, &size);` will work. You should just be careful with the actual data type, as it expects `GLint`. However, you already didn't care about proper typing when you implicitly converted `long` from `ftell` to `unsigned long` either...

Comment: ...Right, I've updated the code with all of the mentioned changes. although it still doesnt render anything.